# Could anyone tell me what is the usage of the circuit within the red frame

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit

The whole circuit is used for measuring voltage, but I am wondering what is the usage the circuit of the red section and how to analysis it? could anybody offer me some anlysis? Pleas ignore some notes in this paper…

[image]

Comment: Two matched 200:1 attenuators. Adjust P1 to match them at LF, adjust C4 for the flattest response on that leg (or squarest square wave), then adjust C8 to match them at HF. For more details, link the AD830 datasheet in your question. But at a guess, you want to attenuate common mode voltages of several hundred volts identically so they can be cancelled out in the AD830 and you are left with the differential voltage.

Comment: That's one of Elektor magazine's beautiful schematics. There should be reference number on it which may help you find the original article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a voltage divider. The whole circuit is a differential amplifier with 2 levels of amplification (S1). The dicvider is made of precision resistors with extra potentiometer P1 to calibrate the input division, if you short circuit the inputs and add a common mode voltage the output should be zero (trimming the P1).
The capacitors are for matching the impedance of the probe. RC for each section must be equal. It is the same as calibrating osciloscope probe and caps are for the same purpose.